issue configuring internal packages with turbo build and using this with nestjs
I've a turbo repo configured with Nestjs, now I need include a shared package so I'm using an internal package, in my root package.json I included
"packages/*"
I'm using the tsconfig from another packages, following this structure
https://github.com/ejazahm3d/fullstack-turborepo-starter/tree/master/packages
my internal packages is named common_types and this is the package.json
{
    "name": "common_types",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "exports": {
        "./dtos": {
            "types": "./src/dto.ts",
            "default": "./src/dto.js"
        },
        "./entities": {
            "types": "./src/entity.ts",
            "default": "./src/entity.js"
        },
        "./shared": {
            "types": "./src/shared.ts",
            "default": "./src/shared.js"
        }
    },

    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "latest",
        "tsconfig": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "dev": "tsc --watch",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "description": "shared types and dtos for the project"
}


my common_types structure is like this
 package.json
 tsconfig.json
 src/
 ---dto.ts
 ---entity.ts
 ---shared.ts

my common_types tsconfig.json looks like this
{
    "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
    "include": ["."],
    "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"]
}

the base.json looks like this
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

the error that I received is
Cannot find module 'common_types/dtos' or its corresponding type declarations.
There are types at '/project/node_modules/common_types/src/dto.ts', but this result could not be resolved under your current 'moduleResolution' setting. Consider updating to 'node16', 'nodenext', or 'bundler'.ts(2307)
I suspect that the error must be a configuration in my tsconfig, but I'm not understand all these tsconfig options and maybe something is wrong there,any help will be appreciated thank you so much
